# How to customize gInfoWindow

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I want to know how to customize a gInfoWindow, but not just the HTML inside it, also the window its self(no rounded corners,backgroundcolor...)

I am a bit noob with google map API V2, so some step by step tips would be of great help.

This is my current code, so you can give me some tips on how i should modify it:

```
var marker1 = new GMarker(new GLatLng(53.117024,79.04068), {  
        draggable: false,  
        title: 'My marker'        
        }); 

              GEvent.addListener(marker1, "click", function() {  
        marker1.openInfoWindowHtml('<div>Custom inner xhtml</div>');        
        });  

                map.addOverlay(marker1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use version 2?  Google maps version 3 has a utility library that allows you to alter the info window appearance, InfoBox and InfoBubble.

[Google Maps Utility Library v3](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries)